# Javascript: %s or %d represents string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, passport.js

Can someone please explain what's happening here? I see `%d` and `%s` but I don't see these declared or written anywhere else in the code. What the heck does this mean/ do in javascript? I'm assuming it's a sort of string templating that I've never seen before?

```js
passport.deserializeUser(
  (id, done) => {
    debug('will deserialize user.id=%d', id)
    User.findById(id)
      .then(user => {
        debug('deserialize did ok user.id=%d', user.id)
        done(null, user)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        debug('deserialize did fail err=%s', err)
        done(err)
      })
  }
)
```

Comment: It’s not part of JavaScript, just seemingly something that `debug` interprets. What is `debug`? (It might be making use of Node’s built-in [util.format](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args).)

Comment: @Ryan interesting... it's an npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug - and looks like `util.format` is exactly what it's using.

Comment: This is just part of the functionality of console object, which presumably `debug`  is using.

Comment: The results are written in the debug console. just open your command-line or terminal and run it using this `node debug [script.js | -e "script" | <host>:<port>]` command.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

What you are seeing there is the string substitution patterns that are built into `console.log()` or `console.debug()`.

The pattern goes as I have presented below:

`%s` *for a String*

`%d` *or* `%i` *for Number*

`%f` *for Floating points*

`%o` *for an Object*

`%j` *for an JSON*

So essentially you are replacing the specifier with the values supplied as so:

```
var name = 'Chris';
console.log('Hi, my name is %s.', name);
// Hi, my name is Chris.

console.debug('Hi, my name is %s.', name);
// Hi, my name is Chris.
```

Docs:

- [Docs for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#string_substitution_and_formatting)
- [Docs for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Using_string_substitutions)
- [Docs for IE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/javascript-console-commands?view=vs-2019#ConsoleLog)
- [Docs for Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args)
- [Docs for Spec](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter)

Comment: Since when has this been a part of console.log!? Wow I can't believe I've never heard of this before.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how long this has been around for; however, I know it is more or less browser specific. With that being said, there are it's limitations as each 'modern' browser has its own JavaScript debugging handler/application.

Comment: Basically, this is Javascript implementing it's own version of printf. Search around for printf a bit; it stems from way back. It's rudimentary String templating. It is a bit like regex in that it's this sort of mini language embedded in just about all full-blown programming languages. It is much less standardized but that's not so much of a problem because it is dead simple anyway. Another one that comes to mind is escape codes like `\n`, `\s` etc, which are also in almost all languages in the string literals.

Answer (score 6):

`console.log()` and `console.debug()` use printf-style formatting. Below are the officially supported formatters:

**Formatter representation:**

- `%O` Pretty-print an Object on multiple lines.
- `%o` Pretty-print an Object all on a single line.
- `%s` String.
- `%d` Number (both integer and float).
- `%j` JSON. Replaced with the string '[Circular]' if the argument contains circular references.
- `%%` Single percent sign ('%'). This does not consume an argument.

The results are written in the debug console. just open your command-line or terminal and run it using this:

```
node debug [script.js | -e "script" | <host>:<port>] command
```

Comment: I ran the command but I get errors: -bash: -e: command not found
-bash: host: No such file or directory
(node:62955) There was an internal error in Node's debugger. Please report this bug.
write EPIPE
Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:804:14)

Comment: Which environment are you using Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: @Tecci I'm using a mac

Comment: Then I suggest to install the `node-inspector` with this command: `sudo npm install -g node-inspector --unsafe-perm`

Answer (score 4):

`%c` :  You can give a style to log text with CSS .

```
console.log("%c YourText", "color:blue; font-weight:bold;");
```

You can create multiple style for different console log text.

```
console.log("%c Text1 %c Text2 %c Text3", "color:red;", "color:green;", "color:blue;");
```

Comment: This is really impressive!

Comment: Where is this documented? If it wasn't for your answer I wouldn't have been able to figure out what %c does. I found %c in the specs but it isn't fully specified. https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger

Comment: @maslancan: I didn't get it. Can you please explain about "%c" further?

Answer (score 1):

That is probably something specific of the debug(), since there is no built-in string formatting in Javascript (not without a library).

However, %d is replaced by an integer and the %s is replaced by a string. Example:

```
debug("I'm %s and I'm %d years old", "John", 10)
```

Should print: I'm John and I'm 10 years old.

Here is a library you could use if you're interested: http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf

Comment: Thanks @Bruno, yea debug is an npm module npmjs.com/package/debug

Comment: Glad to help @Anna !

Answer (score 1):

The % output Format specifiers %d %s etc  come from ANSI C
so it is coming into node thru a library -- in this case util.format
https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args

Answer (score -4):

for simple format like `%03d`, `lodash.padStart` could just do the job.

```
_.padStart(x, 3, '0')
```