# What order does `console.log` with multiple arguments and multiple `%s` substitutions print in?

Tags: javascript, console.log, substitution

I have this chunk of code:

```js
const foo = "hello",
  world = 'world';
console.log("%s,%s!", world, "hey", "javascript", foo);
```

```html
<h1>Check the browser developer tools console for the output</h1>
```

It logs `world,hey! javascript hello`.

I want to understand why it printed `"!"` in the fourth place? How does it decide what to print? Is there any rule?

Comment: [string sub SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406146/javascript-s-or-d-represents-string) and should there be a question/answer to explain the default behavior of a language

Comment: I think the question needs one more thing to be reopened.  It needs to say why you expect something _different than what was actually printed_ to be printed.  Each substitution corresponds to one argument, so if there's any proposed logic (even if it is a misunderstanding) then the question should state that.  For example, maybe you thought only arguments of type string were substituted?  or that all arguments would be concatenated into a single string first? IDK, but you should say what you're thinking so we can correct any misunderstanding, instead of just redocumenting console.log for you.

Comment: I'm wondering if you expected it to print `"%s,%s! world hey javascript hello`? If so, that just means you didn't read the [documentation](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#supporting-ops) about how the formatter works,  which says, _"The formatter operation tries to format the first argument provided, using the other arguments. It will try to format the input until no formatting specifiers are left in the first argument, or no more arguments are left."_

Comment: @Wyck "*I think the question needs one more thing to be reopened. It needs to say why you expect something different than what was actually printed to be printed.*" no, it doesn't. A Q&A should be maximally useful to future visitors. Stating some expectation and having answers having to address why the behaviour is *not* that, is less useful than just focusing on what the behaviour *is* and why. There is no reason to burden future visitors with why something that doesn't happen does not indeed happen because it should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [string substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console#using_string_substitutions) feature of the [Web Console API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console_API).
If you provide more arguments (after the first one) than you have substitution specifiers (such as `%s`) in the first argument, then the remaining arguments will be printed after the substituted first argument.

A [`console.log` call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console/log#syntax) should be used in *one* of these two forms:

- `console.log(value1, value2, value3)`
- `console.log("substitutions %s and %s", substitution1, substitution2)`

However, you are mixing the two forms and pass a larger number of arguments than you have substitutions for.

The MDN documentation isn’t quite clear on what will happen when you do this, but there is a hint in the section for [styling console output](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console#styling_console_output) (using `%c`):

> You may use `%c` multiple times:
>
> ```js
> console.log(
>   "Multiple styles: %cred %corange",
>   "color: red",
>   "color: orange",
>   "Additional unformatted message"
> );
> ```

There are two `%c`s but three strings that follow after, the first two of which are CSS rules, but the third one says `"Additional unformatted message"`, hinting at the fact that this string will be unrelated to the substitutions so far.

### Specification

To be certain, we’ll have to take a look at the [specification](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#log).
All output-producing methods of `console` delegate to the [Logger](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger) operation.
This operation takes all the arguments that you pass as a list called *args*.
Steps 1 through 4 are not relevant; they only apply to cases where you pass less than 2 arguments, but you pass 5.

Step 5 is now important:

> 5. […], perform Printer(*logLevel*, Formatter(*args*)).

[Formatter](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter)(*args*) is called next.
Its description says (bold formatting mine):

> The formatter operation tries to format the first argument provided, using the other arguments.
> It will try to format the input **until no formatting specifiers are left in the first argument**, or no more arguments are left.
> It returns a list of objects suitable for printing.

Formatter is an algorithm that recursively consumes the first two arguments and merges them into one *partially formatted* argument corresponding to the first formatting specifier.
If none are left at the end, the remaining arguments do not get consumed, they stay the same, and the recursion terminates.

In the algorithm, the first steps take the first two arguments, and find the first formatting specifier in the first argument.
Since this will find the first `%s` in the first argument, this will cause the `%s` to be replaced by the stringified second argument.
Then, Formatter is called again with the replaced first argument, and the remaining arguments, starting with the third one; the second one has already been used, so it gets discarded.

### Full visualization of algorithm

To visualize the entire process (using the algorithms as of [2023-01-18 at 14:43:58 UTC](https://web.archive.org/web/20230118144358/https://console.spec.whatwg.org)):

| Where are we? | JavaScript code or spec operation step | Concrete interpretation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JavaScript environment | `console.log("%s,%s!", world, "hey", "javascript", foo)` | `console.log("%s,%s!", "world", "hey", "javascript", "hello")` |
| Specification | log(...*data*) | log(`"%s,%s!"`, `"world"`, `"hey"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"`) |
| [log](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#log)(...*data*) | Perform Logger(`"log"`, data). | Logger(`"log"`, « `"%s,%s!"`, `"world"`, `"hey"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"` ») |
| [Logger](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger)(`"log"`, data) | - If *args* is empty, return. - Let *first* be *args*[0]. - Let *rest* be all elements following *first* in *args*. - If *rest* is empty, perform Printer(*logLevel*, « *first* ») and return. | - *args* is the list « `"%s,%s!"`, `"world"`, `"hey"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"` » - *logLevel* is `"log"` - *first* is `"%s,%s!"` - *rest* is the list « `"world"`, `"hey"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"` » This is not applicable since *args* and *rest* are both not empty. |
|  | Otherwise, perform Printer(*logLevel*, Formatter(*args*)). | Printer(`"log"`, Formatter(« `"%s,%s!"`, `"world"`, `"hey"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"` »)) |
| [Formatter](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter)(*args*) | If *args*’s size is 1, return *args*. | Not applicable. |
|  | Let *target* be the first element of *args*. | *target* is `"%s,%s!"`. |
|  | Let *current* be the second element of *args*. | *current* is `"world"`. |
|  | Find the first possible format specifier *specifier*, from the left to the right in *target*. | *specifier* is `"%s"`. |
|  | If no format specifier was found, return *args*. | Not applicable. |
|  | Otherwise: If *specifier* is `"%s"`, let *converted* be the result of Call(%String%, `undefined`, « *current* »). | *converted* is `String.call(undefined, "world")`, which is `"world"`.<sup>1</sup> The other cases do not apply. |
|  | If any of the previous steps set *converted*, replace *specifier* in *target* with *converted*. | *converted* has been set; *target* is now `"world,%s!"`.<sup>2</sup> |
|  | Let *result* be a list containing *target* together with the elements of *args* starting from the third onward. | *result* is the list « `"world,%s!"`, `"hey"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"` » |
|  | Return Formatter(*result*). | Formatter(« `"world,%s!"`, `"hey"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"` ») |
| [Formatter](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter)(*args*), recursively | If *args*’s size is 1, return *args*. | Not applicable. |
|  | Let *target* be the first element of *args*. | *target* is `"world,%s!"`. |
|  | Let *current* be the second element of *args*. | *current* is `"hey"`. |
|  | Find the first possible format specifier *specifier*, from the left to the right in *target*. | *specifier* is `"%s"`. |
|  | If no format specifier was found, return *args*. | Not applicable. |
|  | Otherwise: If *specifier* is `"%s"`, let *converted* be the result of Call(%String%, `undefined`, « *current* »). | *converted* is `String.call(undefined, "hey")`, which is `"hey"`.<sup>1</sup> The other cases do not apply. |
|  | If any of the previous steps set *converted*, replace *specifier* in *target* with *converted*. | *converted* has been set; *target* is now `"world,hey!"`.<sup>2</sup> |
|  | Let *result* be a list containing *target* together with the elements of *args* starting from the third onward. | *result* is the list « `"world,hey!"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"` » |
|  | Return Formatter(*result*). | Formatter(« `"world,hey!"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"` ») |
| [Formatter](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter)(*args*), recursively, again | If *args*’s size is 1, return *args*. | Not applicable. |
|  | Let *target* be the first element of *args*. | *target* is `"world,hey!"`. |
|  | Let *current* be the second element of *args*. | *current* is `"javascript"`. |
|  | Find the first possible format specifier *specifier*, from the left to the right in *target*. | *specifier* is not found. |
|  | If no format specifier was found, return *args*. | Return the list « `"world,hey!"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"` ». |
| Continuing with Logger | Continuing with this step: Otherwise, perform Printer(*logLevel*, Formatter(*args*)). | Printer(`"log"`, « `"world,hey!"`, `"javascript"`, `"hello"` ») |
| [Printer](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer)(*logLevel*, *args*) |  | Implementation-defined operation to produce the expected output “`world,hey!` `javascript` `hello`”. |

---

<sup>1</sup>: `String.call(undefined, current)` is the same as `String(current)`. Try passing something other than a string to see more interesting results. A `Date` object, for example, will have its `toString` method invoked.

<sup>2</sup>: This is roughly equivalent to `target = target.replace(/(?<!%)%s/, converted)`.